# When the following query is executed shows the following error

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO tbl_vacancy_poojai 
(vc_serial_no,vc_poojai_name,vc_poojai_amount,vc_poojai_time,
vc_book_date,vc_vacancy,vc_bok_poj,vc_type,vc_block) 
VALUES (
(SELECT vc_serial_no FROM tbl_tot_vacancy_poojai),
(SELECT vc_poojai_name FROM tbl_tot_vacancy_poojai),
(SELECT vc_poojai_amount FROM tbl_tot_vacancy_poojai),
(SELECT vc_poojai_time FROM tbl_tot_vacancy_poojai),
'04/02/2018',
(SELECT vc_vacancy FROM tbl_tot_vacancy_poojai),
('04/02/2018'+(SELECT vc_serial_no FROM tbl_tot_vacancy_poojai)),
(SELECT vc_type FROM tbl_tot_vacancy_poojai),1)
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.**strong text

Can anyone guide me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Good try. This is more like what you want:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_vacancy_poojai 
(vc_serial_no,vc_poojai_name,vc_poojai_amount,vc_poojai_time,
vc_book_date,vc_vacancy,vc_bok_poj,vc_type,vc_block) 
SELECT vc_serial_no,vc_poojai_name,vc_poojai_amount,
vc_poojai_time '04/02/2018',vc_vacancy,
'04/02/2018'+vc_serial_no,vc_type
FROM tbl_tot_vacancy_poojai
```

`'04/02/2018'+vc_serial_no` might not do what you think it does

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because of your select query returns more than one row. you need to select one record only to insert from the sub query. So specify the `where` condition or use `select top 1`.

Comment: Yes, how can I insert more rows if my select query returns more than one row?